# I have getting this error even i have initialized the path for flutter in specific directory

Tags: flutter, terminal

[image]

Flutter failed to create file at "C:\Users\development\projects\first_app\lib\main.dart". The flutter tool cannot access
the file or directory.

Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current
user.

Answer (score 0):

Check your windows user permissions. If you loged in as a normal user and not as admin on your windows maschine. Its possible that you have not the write permissions for this folder.

or Disable Controlled Folder Access

Windows Security ->Virus & threat protection ->Manage settings ->Controlled folder access ->Turn off Controlled folder access

Comment: i hve checked ...and i m logged in as Administrator

Comment: Have edit my answer, try second solution. best regards